# nodeJS prevent access to code for variable passed into a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins

I'm creating a plugin system using the following:

```
function Plugin(thingy, code)
{
    var GLOBAL    = null;
    var arguments = null;
    var process   = null;
    var require   = null;

    eval(code);
};

plugins.push(new Plugin(thingy, code));
```

Please don't get too excited about the eval(), using ('vm') or a sandbox is not an option as this will be a long running object until the user unloads it. It will also be running in it's own nodeJS instance so they can't affect other users. I'd still have the same problem passing in this object reference to a sandbox system anyway.

What I am concerned about is someone seeing the code of the thingy object that has functions they need to use e.g shoot()

```
console.log(thingy.shoot.toString());
```

A way around this was the following:

```
function thingy()
{
    // They can't see this
    var _shoot = function(someone)
    {
        // Load weapon
        // Aim
        // Fire
    };

    // They can see this
    this.shoot = function(someone)
    {
        _shoot(someone);
    };
};
```

This way if they console.log(thingy.shoot.toString()) they'll only see _shoot(someone); and not the actual code that handles the shooting process.

Please could someone help me with the following:

1. Is there an easier way to limit access to a passed in variables code?
2. I'm setting GLOBAL, arguments, process and require to null; are there others I need to worry about?

Comment: Yes I am getting excited about `eval`. Either you trust the code, or you don't. If you don't (and need to try to "hide" something), then you're on the wrong path here. There are many other things you would need to worry about, too many in fact to get it completely secure.

Comment: If I'd be to hack this, I'd start with overwriting `Plugin` or its prototype methods, using global eval or the `Function` constructor etc.

Comment: @Bergi: Like I said, I don't care what their code does. I just don't want them to see mine.

How would overriding my functions give them more access than the existing function had in the first place? Can they magically break out of context?

Comment: Yes, they will be able to break out of context. Btw, the simplest way to inspect your code would be `thingy.toString()`.

Comment: Please could you tell me how? They only have access to the code in the eval().

Comment: …and the code in the eval has direct access to the `thingy` parameter of `Plugin`.

Comment: Which brings me back to my original question. Is it possible to do what I'm doing in a simpler way without polluting the code with double functions?

Comment: I don't really know that, I'm just saying that your current way (with "double functions") doesn't even work.